# Composite primary key and foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a design suggestion from all you experts

So I have tables as below:

Table 1

```
( A integer not null
, B char(1) not null
, C integer not null
, D not null
, primary key (A, B, C) i.e. composite key
)
```

Table 2

```
( A integer not null
, B char(2) not null
, C integer not null
primary key (A, B,C) composite key
)
```

Table 3

```
( A integer not null
, B char(2) not null
 , D not null
primary key (A, B, D)
)
```

I want to create a relationship between table 1 and 2 and Table 1 and 3.

Table 1 being the parent table and table 2 and 3 being the child table of Table 1. I can easily create relationship between table 1 and table 2 but I get an error when I try to create relationship between 1 and 3 because foreign key can not be the part of composite key and it has to be the whole composite key. I would highly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Well...by the definition of a foreign key you can't use only part of the primary key. Take your example and say you wanted to use A as the foreign key. But there are 10 rows in Table1 with that value. Which row would the foreign key belong to??? It doesn't make logical sense. Perhaps if you could explain your situation with some meaning instead of Table1, ColA we can help.

Comment: Missing some column types in there - does that DDL actually run?

Comment: If you add a `UNIQUE` index to Table 1 for cols A, B, D then this three cols can be used as a foreign key to Table 3... If these three are not unique in T1 then they do not constitute a *key* in the table, hence they cannot be a foreign key in a different table.

Answer (score 0):

Is this kinda what you're looking for?

```
create table table1 (
    A int not null ,
    B char(1) not null ,
    D int not null ,
    constraint pkTable1 primary key clustered ( A , B , D )
    )
create table table2 (
    A int not null ,
    B char(1) not null ,
    C int not null ,
    constraint pkTable2 primary key clustered ( A , B , C ) ,
    constraint fkABC@table2 foreign key ( A , B , C ) references table1 ( A , B , D )
    )
create table table3 (
    A int not null ,
    B char(1) not null ,
    D int not null ,
    constraint fkABC@table3 foreign key ( A , B , D ) references table1 ( A , B , D )
    )
```

Note the `foreign key ( A , B , *D* )` piece.  Not sure if you'd a primary key on table2 or not, based on the wording of the question, but there it is anyway.

All that said, if `table2` is *subordinate* to `table1`, my inclination would be to do something like:

```
create table table1 (
    t1ID int identity(1,1) not null ,
    constraint uni_t1ID@table1 unique nonclustered ( t1ID ) ,
    A int not null ,
    B char(1) not null ,
    C int not null ,
    constraint pkTable1 primary key clustered ( A , B , C )
    )
create table table2 (
    t2ID int identity(1,1) not null ,
    constraint uci_t2id@table2 unique nonclustered ( t2id ) ,
    t1ID int not null ,
    constraint fk_t1ID@table2 foreign key ( t1ID ) references table1 ( t1ID )
    )
create table table3 (
    t3ID int identity(1,1) not null ,
    constraint uci_t3id@table3 unique nonclustered ( t3id ) ,
    t1ID int not null ,
    constraint fk_t1ID@table3 foreign key ( t1ID ) references table1 ( t1ID )
    )
```

Depending on preference (some people prefer non-sensical primary keys, some prefer primary keys that make some degree of sense to a human), you could replace the unique indexes on the identity fields with primary keys, and be sure to place a unique index on (A,B,C) to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Did my question confuse you? Because you totally ignored the column D

Comment: Well, perhaps it did - did you notice that I included column D in there as part of the relationship?  Otherwise, I guess I missed your question - can you clarify?